# Unity 2D player controller improvements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written the following code as a top down 2D player controller in Unity. It works, but while the sprite direction changes quickly based on key presses, the animation takes a few frames to update. This gives the impression that the sprite is 'gliding' sidewards rather than actually walking in that direction. Is this just due to the way Animator works or is there a way to fix this?

Additionally, should I be concerned about setting position of the GameObject in Update as movement speed will then be dependant on frame rate (if my understanding is correct)? Is there a less clumsy way of doing this?

```
public class playerController : MonoBehaviour
{

private Animator animator;
private float speed = 0.04f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    animator = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
    animator.SetInteger("Direction", 0);
}

void Update()
{
    var vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if (vertical > 0)
    {
        animator.SetInteger("Direction", 2);
    }
    else if (vertical < 0)
    {
        animator.SetInteger("Direction", 0);
    }
    else if (horizontal < 0)
    {
        animator.SetInteger("Direction", 1);
    }
    else if (horizontal > 0)
    {
        animator.SetInteger("Direction", 3);
    }

    gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2(gameObject.transform.position.x + (speed * horizontal), gameObject.transform.position.y + (speed*vertical));
}
}
```

Comment: You need to "stop" moving if  the animation is chaning the sprite direction.

Comment: @Chopi so I should change it so the direction variable is only set when the axis changes, and then stop movement until the state matches the expected state? I can't see how to check the state from the animator API.

Comment: I think you will need to code a little bit, like a delay to response when the player change the direction.